# Delphi webbrowser клик по классу

Tags: delphi, webbrowser

```
<div class="add_friend blue_button">Нажать</div>
```

Уважаемые, подскажите, как кликнуть по диву?

```
lnks := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).links;
   for i := 0 to lnks.length - 1 do
      begin
      lnk := lnks.item(varEmpty, OleVariant(i)) as IHTMLElement;
      if lnk.className = 'add_friend' then
               begin
               lnk.click;

      end;
   end;
```

Данный код пропускает из виду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

класс то add_friend blue_button

а не как у вас в условии

lnk.className = 'add_friend'

Comment: Всё равно игнорит.

Comment: попробуй выведи в мемо все значения lnk.className
может твой div во фрейме и ты его вообще не получаешь этим кодом.

я проверил класс твоего DIV'a равен add_friend blue_button
на си шарпе, но тут не критично думаю
IHTMLElement a_tag = FCurrentWebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")[0].DomElement as IHTMLElement;
            return a_tag.className;